# Does MooseX::Declare require the '{' to be on the same line as 'method'?

Tags: perl, moose

This seems to work:

```
use MooseX::Declare;

class Example {
    method my_method() {

    }
}
```

This seems to not create the method:

```
use MooseX::Declare;
class Example {
    method my_method() 
    {

    }
}
```

Am I missing something, or is it a restriction of `MooseX::Declare` that the opening curly brace has to go on the same line as 'method'?

--edit--

`MooseX::Declare` = 0.35

`Devel::Declare` = 0.006004 - looks like I am down version in `Devel::Declare`, later versions don't seem to be available within ActiveState perl due to some build issue: http://code.activestate.com/ppm/Devel-Declare/ (up to and including 0.006008)

Comment: The build issue is bizarre.  Devel::Declare isn't doing anything odd in its Makefile.PL that would cause it to hang.  There are many alternative PPM repositories: http://win32.perl.org/wiki/index.php?title=PPM_Repositories  You can also use Strawberry Perl which comes with a compiler and can install most modules from CPAN.  http://strawberryperl.com/

Comment: @Schwern, No need to switch to Strawberry. `cpan` works perfectly fine in AS as well. If you don't have a compiler, AS will download, install and use `mingw`.

Comment: The problem is actually in MooseX::Method::Signatures. I have 0.37 (latest).

Comment: ...which also uses Devel::Declare. I have 0.006008 (latest). I don't think it's a problem with Devel::Declare problem, though.

Comment: What's up with MooseX::Method::Signatures (and thus MooseX::Declare) not giving an error when it encounters something it can't handle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that should work.  You might have to upgrade Devel::Declare, which does the syntax magic, or MooseX::Declare.